# Hello, how can I put different colors in a p element?

Tags: html, css, text, colors

```
<p class="desc-title">
            command activate;<br>
               monke brain: insert code.<br>
               monke html: evolve level 1.<br>
               monke css: evolve level 2.<br>
               monke javascript: evolve level 3.<br>
               monke: web basics complete.<br>
           </p>
```

Sorry for the noob question but how can i can have different colors in a single p element
i want to change the monke text color to red and all the other text to light blue.
thank you.

Comment: add a tag `<span>` and use css to style it

Comment: do i need to use a class? like <span class ="#"> ? also do i need to seperate them in style? or i can put it inside the  p class style?

Comment: you don't need a class for span if you want to style only monke word. So you cando `<span>monke</span>` and then in your css `.desc-title span{color:red;}`

Answer (score 2):

```css
.desc-title{
  color: lightblue;
}

.desc-title .monke{
  color:red
}
```

```html
<p class="desc-title">
    command activate;<br>
   <span class="monke">monke</span> brain: insert code.<br>
   <span class="monke">monke</span> html: evolve level 1.<br>
   <span class="monke">monke</span> css: evolve level 2.<br>
   <span class="monke">monke</span> javascript: evolve level 3.<br>
   <span class="monke">monke</span>: web basics complete.<br>
 </p>
```

Comment: You don't need javascript to do this.....

Comment: thanks man. kinda afraid to ask a question here bcs i seen comments about overflow sometimes being toxic to new users/noob.

Comment: @Sfili_81 Just saw your comments. I was editing already before seeing your comments

Comment: For this answer is correct only css solution, js solution is useless in this case

Comment: @Sfili_81 Yeah you are right. CSS is sufficient

Comment: @woopwoop, not all are the same here. Most are helpful and kindness